# "unconcatenating" a field and pivoting mysql or talend

Tags: mysql, talend

I am new to mysql and databases in general.  I've come across a problem that I can't seem to find a solution too.  I'm not sure even how to word the scenario.

Basically I have a concatenated field that I need to take "explode" and make each value its of that field its own row.  I'm pulling this data from a daily feed, so this needs to be automated as either a trigger, stored procedure, or scheduled job in Talend.  Here is a simplified version of the situation.  Please see the "current file format" and the "desired outcome" pics.  Sorry- this is my first post here!  Any help would be appreciated!

I am using a mysql database.  Currently the file is coming in via csv export, but I will be connecting via Talend Open Studio to sync the data.  See the links below for and example. [Here is a sample.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/00kqz809jm0sh6t/Sample.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Can you illustrate with sample data (input an expected result)?

Comment: Your pdf document is unavailable, could you please post an example ?

Comment: have a look at the tNormalize component in Talend.

Answer (score 0):

A precise answer is difficult without seeing your code, and the sample link returns 404 for me. You should be able to do this within Talend. Try using Talend’s `tExtractDelimitedFields` or `tExtractRegexFields` commands to achieve the result you want.